# Can one get access to DataCloud in a dev org?

Tags: certification, setup, developer-org, datacloud, trial

Are there trial orgs or dev orgs where one can play with datacloud and look at the configurations? I want to see how to set up the data streams and set up data models and play with the configurations and looking for an environment to do that on my own and was wondering if someone could guide me on how we can get access to an org to be able to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update from TDX24 - you can now sign up for a Developer Edition with Data Cloud - it only lasts for 5 days, but anyone can sign up - more details here:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/create-a-data-stream-in-data-cloud/get-started-with-a-data-cloud-developer-edition